# Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 keymaps change randomly

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, keyboard, mate, shortcut-keys

On Ubuntu 18.04/20.04, in the Mate, XFCE and Ubuntu (default) UI's, I've been having keys get remapped without warning, sometimes as I'm typing.

In Mate, I was seeing these keys remapped:  L -> lock screen, I, E, S, return, backspace.

I thought this was quite odd and further thought my computer had been hacked.  We spent several days changing passwords.  I ran virus scans, rootkit scans, etc. without finding any problems.

Separately, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a different computer.  Mate was working fine, until it started showing the exact same behaviors after a little while (about a day or two).  On both of these computers, I switched to Ubuntu (default).  I also tried XFCE on the first computer, it worked fine.  I left it running overnight (the first computer runs all the time); the next day some of the keys on XFCE were messed up, but differently from Mate.

The first computer (both of these are laptops), Ubuntu (default) UI was fine until I rebooted this evening.  The mouse would not work correctly, many keys were remapped.  It almost looked like it had gone into an Adaptive Mode, but I couldn't get it out.  I switched to Ubuntu (Classic), which seems to be working for now.  I'm thinking it's just a matter of time before the keys get remapped also.

All the settings I've been able to figure out all show the keyboard definitions as correct for English (US).

Has anyone seen anything like this?  I haven't found anything like doing searches.  Switching desktops is not an option.  I've been running Linux in some flavor or another since 1992, and I've NEVER seen anything like this; this behavior started about 3 weeks ago.  Since this is happening on two different laptops from different manufacturers, I'm thinking it is not a hardware problem.  If I exit out of GUIs to the command line, the keys work fine on the command line; terminal sessions running inside the GUIs are also affected.  Also, I can ssh into the computers just fine and the keys from the source computer respond correctly.

I really could use some ideas on this!  Please let me know what info to provide to help diagnose this.

Thank You for your help!!!!

Comment: What keyboards are you using? are they wireless as it sounds more like a wireless networking issue to me. For comparisons with machines, where they using the same stacks (GA or HWE?  a 20.04 GA stack is identical to 18.04 using HWE for example?)

Comment: Keyboards are wired.  The first laptop, the keyboard is using USB, but I also found the built-in keyboard had the same behavior.  The second laptop only using built-in keyboard, same behavior.  Both are 20.04 GA.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on how to fix the keymapping problems?  Suggestions?  Need more info?